# rabbitmq-server -detached with non-root user is blocking

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, centos, dockerfile, root

I'm running rabbitmq-server on a `centos:8` based Docker image.

To install rabbitmq:

```
COPY yum/rabbitmq_erlang.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/rabbitmq_erlang.repo
RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.rpm.sh | bash && \
    yum -y install rabbitmq-server && \
    rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management && \
    chmod -R 777 /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
```

I run Docker as a custom non-root user due to security requirements.

Then my start-up script runs

```sh
...
rabbitmq-server -detached
...
```

However this command blocks and doesn't let my script continue running.

I know I can run

```sh
rabbitmq-server &
```

But I'd prefer running properly as daemon if possible. It seems to be tightly coupled with running as non-root, because running same image as root works fine.

Command line reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server.8.html#OPTIONS

Comment: are you building custom rabbitmq image and `rabbitmq-server` is the main container process?  or `rabbitmq-server` process will run in addition to some main container process (having pid 1)

Comment: it runs in addition, that's why I need it to run as a daemon

Comment: did `rabbitmq-server &` run succesfully?

Comment: @rok yeah it runs successfully

Answer (score 1):

`rabbitmq-server -detached` is the way to run `rabbitmq` in the background. These [lines](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/4ec23dddf668cac6aeecef594182c62a2356f450/Dockerfile-ubuntu.template#L210) from the official `rabbitmq` Dockerfile might be helpful.

However, running `rabbitmq` and any infra service as non pid 1 in Docker container is highly discouraged and against docker best practices.

To give you a couple of reasons why:

- you need to replicate carefully in your Dockerfile instructions from the official Rabbitmq [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).
- when your multi-service container receives SIGTERM signal, its handler has to invoke graceful shutdown of `rabbitmq` as well.

You may want check [these](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) docker official instructions on how you may try to do it.

Comment: I fully understand the best practices and motivations for them, but don't see why the official way to run in the background is not working in my scenario, do you think its a bug in rabbitmq?